# Convert dynamic object to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

How do I to convert a dynamic to NameValueCollection?

I tried converting it to a dictionary and then to a NameValueCollection but it will throw exceptions for different types.

```
[...]
  NameValueCollection item = ((IDictionary<string, object>)dynamicObject).ToNameValueCollection();
[...]

public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
  var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
  foreach (var pair in dictionary)
  {
    string value = pair.Value == null ? null : value = pair.Value.ToString();
    nameValueCollection.Add(pair.Key.ToString(), value);
  }
  return nameValueCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found out the answer:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public static class Extensions
{
  public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection<T>(this T dynamicObject)
  {
    var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dynamicObject))
    {
      string value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(dynamicObject).ToString();
      nameValueCollection.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, value);
    }
    return nameValueCollection;
  }
}
```

To use it:

```
public void DoStuff(dynamic obj) 
{
  NameValueCollection items = obj.ToNameValueCollection();
  // Do stuff with items
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get an error: `Invalid column name "ToNameValueCollection".` I have a result set from `WebMatrix.Data.Database.Query`, and I was hoping to use this to convert each row to a NameValueCollection: `foreach(var Row in ResultSet) { NameValueCollection N = Row.ToNameValueCollection(); // do stuff with n }`